# VSCode TypeScript intellisense is not type narrowing

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

Simple question, given some TypeScript:

```
function runInnerHTML () {
  const container = document.getElementById('test-inner-html')
  invariant(container)
  beginTest(container)
}

function beginTest (el: HTMLElement) {
...
}
```

And a `tsconfig.json` of:

```json
{
  "include": ["src", "types"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "baseUrl": "./",

    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "importsNotUsedAsValues": "error",
    "noEmit": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "useDefineForClassFields": true
  }
}
```

TypeScript compiles the above file just fine  no issues. Critically the `invariant` function successfully narrows the return of `document.getElementById` which is `HTMLElement | null` to just `HTMLElement`. If I remove the invariant line, the compile fails as expected.

However, my VSCode is unhappy because it does not understand the type narrowing that invariant is doing.

[image: Image of failing type narrowing with intellisense]

My understanding is that intellisense should be using the same TS server as the build process. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Ok — the reason this issue was occurring was TypeScript being used in the project was `4.x` and the version of TypeScript being used by VSCode was `3.x`, even though my "global" typescript version was `>=4.x` VSCode has it's own internal version that it uses.

To resolve this, I added a workspace setting with the following:

```json
{
    "typescript.tsdk": "./node_modules/typescript/lib"
}
```

Then returning to the document that was failing and running the VSCode command "TypeScript: Select TypeScript Version." — now the correct version of TS was available to select:

[image]

This resolved the narrowing issues. More details on these configuration options are available [in the TypeScript documentation.](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-compiling#_using-newer-typescript-versions)